# "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel" An error will occur in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

This is Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:201)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:118)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
at com.insu.tripmoto_compose.screen.main.map.EditMarkerDialogKt.EditMarkerDialog(EditMarkerDialog.kt:109)
at com.insu.tripmoto_compose.screen.main.map.MapScreenKt.MapScreen(MapScreen.kt:49)
at com.insu.tripmoto_compose.screen.main.map.MapScreenKt$MapScreen$6.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
at com.insu.tripmoto_compose.screen.main.map.MapScreenKt$MapScreen$6.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:162)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2486)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2754)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3385)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3363)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3363)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3328)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:772)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1047)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:541)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:510)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1035)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:775)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

This is MapScreen.kt

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MapScreen() {
    val activity = LocalContext.current as ComponentActivity
    var markerAddState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var googleMapClickState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    BackHandler {
        activity.finish()
    }
    val singapore = LatLng(1.35, 103.87)
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
    }

    if(googleMapClickState) {
        EditMarkerDialog {
            googleMapClickState = false
        }
    }

    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        onMapClick = {
            if(markerAddState) {
                googleMapClickState = true
            }
        }
    ) {
        Marker(
            state = MarkerState(position = singapore),
            title = "Singapore",
            snippet = "Marker in Singapore"
        )
    }

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset(x = screenWidth - 46.dp, y = screenHeight - 140.dp)
            .size(36.dp)
            .clickable {
                markerAddState = !markerAddState
            },
        painter = painterResource(AppIcon.ic_add_marker),
        tint =
            if(!markerAddState) colorResource(AppColor.gray_4)
            else colorResource(AppColor.primary_800),
        contentDescription = "addMarker",
    )
}
```

This is EditMarkerDialog.kt

```kotlin
@Composable
fun EditMarkerDialog(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val viewModel: MapViewModel by hiltViewModel()
    val marker by viewModel.marker

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() }) {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            elevation = 8.dp
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
                MainTitleText(
                    text = AppText.edit_marker,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                )

                LimitTextField(
                    maxLength = 15,
                    text = AppText.title,
                    value = marker.title,
                    onNewValue = viewModel::onTitleChange,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 8.dp)
                )

                LimitTextField(
                    maxLength = 100,
                    text = AppText.title,
                    value = marker.description,
                    onNewValue = viewModel::onDescriptionChange,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 8.dp)
                )

                Row {
                    BasicButton(
                        text = AppText.cancel,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .weight(1F)
                    ) {
                        onDismiss()
                    }

                    BasicButton(
                        text = AppText.done,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .weight(1F)
                    ) {
                        viewModel.onDoneClick() {
                            onDismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is MapViewModel.kt

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MapViewModel @Inject constructor(
    logService: LogService,
    private val storageService: StorageService
): MyViewModel(logService) {
    val marker = mutableStateOf(MapMarker())

    fun initialize(markerId: String) {
        launchCatching {
            if(markerId != "-1") {
                marker.value = storageService.getMarker(markerId.idFromParameter()) ?: MapMarker()
            }
        }
    }

    fun onTitleChange(newValue: String) {
        marker.value = marker.value.copy(title = newValue)
    }

    fun onDescriptionChange(newValue: String) {
        marker.value = marker.value.copy(description = newValue)
    }

    fun onDoneClick(onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
        launchCatching {
            val editedMarker = marker.value
            var markerId: String? = null

            if(marker.value.id.isNotBlank() && marker.value.description.isNotBlank()) {
                if(editedMarker.id.isBlank()) {
                    markerId = storageService.saveMarker(editedMarker)
                } else {
                    storageService.updateMarker(editedMarker)
                }
                onDismiss()
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application applied Hilt Android App annotation.
And other HiltView Models work normally.

Problems occur when you activate the button and click on the map to create Dialog Composable.
In addition, MapScreen.kt uses a method of saving states as variables because it cannot invoke Composable functions within Google Maps. Is there a better way?

**Thanks**

Comment: try using  val viewModel: MapViewModel by hiltViewModel<MapViewModel>()

Comment: If you don't use Delegate Pattern, no errors will occur!